Removing extra space in phaser 3 text

'm trying to fit the text exactly the height of container. I set the text fontsize same as container height problem is there is a default space.I already set padding to 0. Is there a way to remove the default space of text

Did my answer help you solve.your question, or did I miss something?

could you let us know if your question is solved or not? btw.: If you found a solution please share, or accept a answer, so that the question is marked as solved and we all can learn, from your question. Thank you.

There Are some ways using the setCrop function (link to the documentation), or simply not using background and using a rectangle-gameobject for the background.
If you need this alot you could create a custom GameObject (like in this example)
Here a short demo, show casing the two first options:


document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    },
}; 

function create () {
    let text = this.add.text(10,10, 'BASELINE TEXT')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setColor('#000000')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setBackgroundColor('#ffff00')
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
    
    text.setBackgroundColor('#ffff00')
    
    // ONE Way
    let text2 = this.add.text(220, 10, 'CROP THE TEXT OBJECT')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setColor('#000000')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setBackgroundColor('#cdcdcd')
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

     text2.setCrop( 0, 2, text2.displayWidth, text2.displayHeight- 13);


   // A better way
   let text3Position = {x: 10, y: 40};
        
   this.add.rectangle(text3Position.x + 1, text3Position.y + 3, 220, 22, 0x00ff00)
        .setOrigin(0);
        
   let text3= this.add.text(text3Position.x, text3Position.y, 'NO BACKGROUND')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setColor('#ffffff')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>




Disclaimer: As mentioned above, there are many way's to solve this problem depending on your usecase, there might be a better way, like using a phaser graphics and/or renderTextures.




.container {
  height: 100px; 
}
.text {
  font-size: 100px; 
  line-height: 1;
 letter-spacing: 0;
}




Your answer won't really work with Phaser, since the text is drawn on a canvas. If I'm wrong it might help, if you would elaborate on your answer. Just posting code/html is not always enough.
